# GDAL for python

Tags: python, installation, gdal

I am trying to install GDAL for Python via anaconda prompt but I am getting this error:

[ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1l-h8ffe710_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\geo\Library\bin\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll'
()

I am not sure why I am getting this message.

Thank you for help.
Haifa

Comment: "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\geo\Library\bin\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll' () " means that you don't have permission to access the operating file, usually occurs if the user does not have read or write permission on a file.

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda

Comment: Thank you for the comment.